# Adding Commas to Float or String?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, formatting, nsnumberformatter

I have been trying to find a way to find a way to append commas to a string or float. I have a float which could be anything from 10.50 to 50000000000.99 and would love to be able to format this to add commas to every 3 digits (not including the floats). I know that there is a NSNumberFormatter that can use NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle or NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle but neither of those work with strings/floats. I have tried to split the float into two strings and then try to do a % of length == 3 calculation but it began to get really really messy. I did something similar in Java but it seems to be a lot harder in iOS.

If anyone have any suggestions or ideas? Any information or guidance is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Edit: I know there are posts out there but none of them seem to solve the problem with doubles/floats/strings that end in zeros. For example, if I have a double as 16.00, the formatter will format that into 16. Same thing goes for a 1234.80. The formatter will format it into 1,234.8 instead of 1,234.80 and that is what I am looking for.

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1853949/442328

Comment: possible duplicate of [comma separated thousand NSString stringWithFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853305/comma-separated-thousand-nsstring-stringwithformat)

Comment: `NSNumberFormatter` is what you need. It does work with `float` but you need to wrap the `float` in an `NSNumber` first. For strings, convert to `double` first, then to `NSNumber`.

Comment: @KDaker  I know there are posts out there but none of them seem to solve the problem with doubles/floats/strings that end in zeros. For example, if I have a double as 16.00, the formatter will format that into 16. Same thing goes for a 1234.80. The formatter will format it into 1,234.8 instead of 1,234.80 and that is what I am looking for.

Comment: @rmaddy I have tried NSNumberFormatter before but it seems like it is not converting decimals with ending zeros correctly. Do you know anything that could fix that?

Comment: If you use decimal format, be sure to set the min and max fraction digits to suit your needs.

Comment: @rmaddy I have them both set to 2. [numFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
                    [numFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View this post on NSNumberFormatting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14483290/877032)

The gist of it is to covert the float or double to a NSNumber and then use the NSNumberFormatter on the NSNumber to get a NSString with the desired format.  Something like:

```
double doubleNum = 1000.002;

// Change double to nsnumber:
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:doubleNum];

// Set up the formatter:
NSNumberFormatter *numFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numFormatter setUsesGroupingSeporator:YES];
[numFormatter setGroupingSeparator:@","];
[numFormatter setGroupingSize:3];

// Get the formatted string:
NSString *stringNum = [numFormatter stringFromNumber:num];

NSLog(@"%@",stringNum);
// prints out '1,000.002'
```

Give it a try, there are lots of different formatting settings you can apply.

Comment: It seems that the formatter does not recognize ending Zeros, ie 11.00, 123.80, 1,342.20 all print out without the zeros.

Comment: You can set a 'minimumFractionDigits' property on the formatter. This allows you to force the display of a minimum (or maximum via another property) of fraction digits.  Similar properties exist for the decimal digits as well. See the link for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Read [Apple's guide to formatting numbers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002368-SW1), `NSNumberFormatter` supports both thousand separators and fractional parts. For example see Listing 1 in the referenced doc.